# Data Tables Columns Not Alligned

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I use bootstrap for tabs on my pages. Inside these tabs are JQuery Data Tables. For some reason when a user clicks a tab after the page has loaded the data table's headers do not allign with the rows.

[image]

If I click one of the headers (the button that orders the column) then the columns fix themselves. Can anybody help me out here? I've tried several CSS and Javascript "hacks" to fix this.

Here's where I initialize my data table:

```
$( ".dynamic-table" ).DataTable({
    "scrollY": 450,
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "lengthMenu": [[10, 50, 500, -1], [10, 50, 500, "All"]]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [`columns.adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API method to recalculate columns widths.

From the [manual](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29):

> *Call it when the table becomes visible if hidden when initialized (for example in a tab) or when the data changes significantly.*

```js
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e){
   $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable()
      .columns.adjust();
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/07zdqksw/) for code and demonstration.

> **LINKS**

See [jQuery DataTables – Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs) for solution to the most common problems with jQuery DataTables and Bootstrap Tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. This will sort the first `th` programatically on tab click thus fixing the unalligned headers. It does it twice in order to bring the order back to way it was originally.

```
/* FIX FOR COLUMNS BEING UNALLIGNED */
$(document).on( 'shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    var activeTabPanel = $('.tab-pane.active');
    activeTabPanel.find("th:first").click();
    activeTabPanel.find("th:first").click();
});
```